# Unable to display this Web Part

Tags: sharepoint

*Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.*

---

I have just created a sample team site and added an external content type to it. It's an SQL database. When I added it as an external list in my sharepoint website, it appeared in the quick launch. When I clicked on it I was unable to display it and got the following error message:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To
>   troubleshoot the problem, open this
>   Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation-compatible HTML editor such
>   as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If
>   the problem persists, contact your Web
>   server administrator.
>
> Correlation
>   ID:e1c61ac1-788a-46c6-9311-495a5fa0603f

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Really ... Long .... Title....

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are trying to do from the question...

Comment: It may be good to mention this is about SharePoint 2010.. look up the error in the error logs so you can see what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

First you should turn on verbose logging with ULS.  You will find this in the Centeral Administration site under logging.

You will then have more detail information inside of the ULS logs which should help.  Since you mention external content type and have an error with a correlation id I assume you are working with a beta version of SharePoint 2010.